# Store an array into a specific position of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm creating code in Python and I need to perform some operations with arrays. One of them consists of storing an array in a specific position of another array. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros([2, 2])
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
b[0, 0] = a
print(b)
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Juan Vera/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_11.py", line 6, in <module>
    b[0, 0] = a
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected result is. You should first understand what data types you are working with. For example, `b` is a 2x2 array of zeros, and `a` is a 2x2 array of numbers 0, 1, 1, and 2.

Your code is currently attempting to set the first element of the first array in `b` to the entire 2x2 array `a`. To do so, the element at `b[0, 0]` would have to be of shape (2, 2) and not (1, ) like it currently is.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this array `b` after this?  That will determine what is the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default data-type of `np.zeros` is `np.float64`. Meaning, the array `b` expects its entries to be [64-bit floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

When you pass the line `b[0,0] = a` you get the error that you are trying to squeeze a sequence into an array element.

If you change the data-type of your array `b` to `object`, then `b` expects it's elements to be any old `object`. So you'd have no problems with `b[0, 1]` being a number and `b[0, 0]` being an array.  Like so:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=object)
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])

b[0, 0] = a
```

If this seems overly stuffy/detailed, note that that is one of the tradeoffs with numpy. Numpy provides speed upgrades at the cost of being "closer to the metal". Type specification is one of those upgrades.

Also, you may just be playing around, but in general, I would very much advise someone *not* to use numpy arrays like this in practice (as there's likely a better data structure to fit your needs).

Edit:

If your intent was to broadcast `a` into the `2x2` submatrix starting at position `(0,0)` in `b`, then this example might be helpful:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.zeros((4, 4))
a = np.array([[0, 1],[1,2]])
c = np.array([[3, 4],[5,6]])

b[0:0+a.shape[0], 0:0+a.shape[1]] = a
b[2:2+c.shape[0], 2:2+c.shape[1]] = c

print(b)

# [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 1.  2.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  3.  4.]
#  [ 0.  0.  5.  6.]]
```

*This* way of operating on numpy arrays (where the array storage structure itself doesn't change, just the values of the elements) is perfectly fine. This is because numpy knows *a priori* how much space in memory to assign for the array when the datatype is a numerical one like `float64` or `int`. In contrast, when working with a numpy with dtype `object`, the array is constantly being written and rewritten in memory -- an expensive process that undoes a large benefit of working with numpy (namely, speed improvements in array operations).

Comment: While the `object` approach works, I don't think a beginner should be introduced to it.  Your second sliced approach is best `numpy` practice, whether it's what the OP intended or not.

Comment: The first recommendation worked for my application, thanks. I'm sure there are others ways to do this, but I have an structure way to assembly a huge matrix, and by this way I save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Using just the title "Store an array into a specific position of another array" the following code does this:

```
a = ['x', 'y']
b = [1, 2, 3]
b.insert(0, a)
print(b)
# Outputs 
# [['x', 'y'], 1, 2, 3]
```

Can control the index like so:

```
b.insert(1, a)
# Outputs
# [1, ['x', 'y'], 2, 3]
```

Comment: From a literal perspective, you appear to have answered the question, but OP seems to be using NumPy and is specifically asking about Numpy syntax.

Comment: Yeah I agree that the title and the description provided don't seem to match up. Either way, if someone else searches the title without using numpy then I hope they may find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to overwrite the corresponding "patch" of the array `b`, then use slicing:

```py
b[0:2, 0:2] = a # or b[:, :] if a and b has the same shapes
print(b)
# [[0. 1.]
#  [1. 2.]]
```

On the other hand, although rarely so, if you want to set the `[0, 0]`th element as the array `a`, then try (note `dtype=object`):

```py
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros([2, 2], dtype=object)
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
b[0, 0] = a
print(b)
# [[array([[0, 1],
#        [1, 2]]) 0]
#  [0 0]]
```

In this way `b[0, 0]` is now an array, `b[0, 1] == 0` (a number), and so on. Again, this is rarely what you want, and in general avoided.